# Getting 403 response code even though the site is loading properly on browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I am trying to get response code using httpurlconnection but getting "403" as response code even though the site is properly oading on browser.

URL : "https://www.texanscu.org/home/home"

Here is the code I am using,

```
try {
     String url = "https://www.texanscu.org/home/home";

     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

     conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36");
     conn.setConnectTimeout(2000);
     conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
     conn.setReadTimeout(100000);
     conn.connect();

     int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

    } catch(Exception e) {
         logger.error("Caught exception : {}", e.getMessage);
    }
```

There is no exception. It's just that I am getting the response code as "403".

Comment: Error code says it clearly - you are forbidden from accessing the resource on the server. Maybe you need to authenticate first, maybe you are simply banned. Investigate what exactly is your browser sending - can be cookie, referer, both or anything else server expects to see and as you are not sending it, you get rejected

Comment: I checked every possible request headers but still it didn't worked. Is there any way to deal with this ?

Comment: The url of the GET request is protected by [Captcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA).
That means, the website is not supposed to be used by a non-human user.

Answer (score 1):

I modifed your code a little bit, to see the actual response from server.

```
 try {
            String url = "https://www.texanscu.org/";

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(100000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            conn.setReadTimeout(100000);
            conn.connect();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(responseCode);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getErrorStream())));
            String strCurrentLine;
            while ((strCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(strCurrentLine);
            }


        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So when I execute this code, I see following output :

```
<head>
<title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>
<meta name="captcha-bypass" id="captcha-bypass" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>


<!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/zepto.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.common.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="cf-error-details-wrapper">
      <div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
        <h1 data-translate="challenge_headline">One more step</h1>
        <h2 class="cf-subheadline"><span data-translate="complete_sec_check">Please complete the security check to access</span> www.texanscu.org</h2>
      </div><!-- /.header -->
      
      <div class="cf-section cf-highlight cf-captcha-container">
        <div class="cf-wrapper">
          <div class="cf-columns two">
            <div class="cf-column">
            
              <div class="cf-highlight-inverse cf-form-stacked">
                <form class="challenge-form" id="challenge-form" action="/?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=8f811f0d4e8be53ef88568630d8c627b6a8639a6-1598364414-0-AXcy5nmycYBIOZVpr4NiQNNpsvz-TeYA4kD6NYOYQq8A9OjdxedaBdcfaEp4DM-P6EnhMFryAMIv8_Vi3PM3ukkKw8W4aFv0W4FXhYk4eJgcmPWlA6XdiAQBfIRWqmV7ORtKClPdGo9CgujUYWdpkGr_3hGiUU_bLFp9jf8mF-nCM3s9nex_0MiA916wQSCs-nhaM8_jFGdJ2VmJjczihFz8MFed_zVHNzLG4HHQdcrOl13P4jZy9Y_nhJfAyhVG0ngQXE8y-Slb_c5gvcfGGDa8vrxTpLgrQEF2-SwqkjhJTApfSUn6Y3mtjZ9ZYrA28NDZC1ngeit3IOga5pxB2wcZuYHfatTHy832J_itWa8MrtbDQV_DSWwGroAdC9q10MVYI0CIPzcxzvOrWSUYjlPYRxEKE_cw1mvO5hxsQuPtSlHIMs0bIHUpZl88F16Ki1xr8FEgqGM8aU2-VFlzYjKHh89qHe1MoapqHmZ31Na5Q0LAbGJdl69lGFGhUczHqWL9D015U4Jfpmim3203E23qb5vLnzBu8kJf6ygKDvKn" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
 
  <input type="hidden" name="cf_captcha_kind" value="h">
  <input type="hidden" name="vc" value="">
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/hcaptcha.challenge.js" data-type="normal"  data-ray="5c85e0576bec0faa" async data-sitekey="33f96e6a-38cd-421b-bb68-7806e1764460"></script>
  
  <noscript id="cf-captcha-bookmark" class="cf-captcha-info">
  <h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>
  </noscript>
  <div id="no-cookie-warning" data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="display:none">
    <h1 data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="color:#bd2426;">Please enable Cookies.</h1>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    var a = function() {try{return !!window.addEventListener} catch(e) {return !1} },
      b = function(b, c) {a() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", b, c) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", b)};
      b(function(){
        var cookiesEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)? true : false;
        if(!cookiesEnabled){
          var q = document.getElementById('no-cookie-warning');q.style.display = 'block';
        }
      });
  //]]>
  </script>
  <div id="trk_captcha_js" style="background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/captcha/nojs/h/transparent.gif?ray=5c85e0576bec0faa')"></div>
</form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cf-column">
              <div class="cf-screenshot-container">
                <span class="cf-no-screenshot"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.columns -->
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.captcha-container -->

      <div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
        <div class="cf-columns two">
          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="why_captcha_headline">Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?</h2>
            
            <p data-translate="why_captcha_detail">Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="resolve_captcha_headline">What can I do to prevent this in the future?</h2>
            

            <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_antivirus">If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with malware.</p>

            <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_network">If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run a scan across the network looking for misconfigured or infected devices.</p>
           
              <p data-translate="resolve_captcha_privacy_pass"> Another way to prevent getting this page in the future is to use Privacy Pass. You may need to download version 2.0 now from the <a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/privacy-pass/ajhmfdgkijocedmfjonnpjfojldioehi">Chrome Web Store</a>.</p>
              
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.section -->
      

      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper">
  <p>
    <span class="cf-footer-item">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong>5c85e0576bec0faa</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Your IP</span>: 178.221.185.37</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
    
  </p>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
  window._cf_translation = {};
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Cloudflare is protecting the website you are trying to reach,so they are using anti-DoS system on server."DoS" means a Denial of Service attack. For example, someone configures thousands of machines to hit a website in an attempt to overload it. These automated attacks are done by robots or simply "bots".
Obviously, the system thinks you are a bot. So, there is no way you can reach this endpoint trought java code.

**EDIT** : If found this library :
https://github.com/iambluedev1/cfscrape-java
It's used to bypass Cloudflare's anti-bot page. You can try it.